# JQuery Scroll with position:fixed CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { // document ready
        var contentTop = $('.share').offset().top; // returns number 
        $(window).scroll(function () { // scroll event             
            var wayPoint = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns number               
            if (contentTop < wayPoint) {
                var shareWidth = $('.content').width();
                $('.share-active').width(shareWidth);
                $('.share').replaceWith('<div class="share-active">SOCIAL BUTTONS</div>');
            } else {
                $('.share-active').replaceWith('<div class="share"></div>');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**DEMO** : http://jsfiddle.net/franciscop/b39M4/3/

Somehow the `share-active`div is appearing before the scroll top reaches `share` div. I don't know what I am going wrong.

**Also**, anyway to animate the apperance of the `share-active` div so users are attracted to it.

**Can you help me find where the problem is?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are getting the offset of your element too quickly. When `document.ready` fires the image(s) probably hasn't fully loaded. So you can either give the images on your page specific height values so they take-up the required space before they actually load, or you can use the `window.load` event to get your offset.

The easiest fix would probably be changing:

```
$(function () { // document ready
```

to:

```
$(window).on("load", function () { // window load
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/b39M4/4/

This has the side-effect that your code won't work until the whole page has loaded. So another method would be to update the `contentTop` variable whenever necessary. Once on `document.ready`, once on `window.load` and maybe once each time an image loads. This would make it so the code would initialize faster and more accurately reflect the reality of the webpage's layout.

To animate the appearance of the element you can give it an initial `opacity` of zero and then after adding the element to the DOM, selecting it and animating it into visibility.

Also, you really should throttle the `window.scroll` event handler because some browsers will just lockup since there are so many `window.scroll` events that fire when using the scroll bar.

Comment: Its taking too long for all elements of page to get loaded... Anyway to call the funtion after the main image load itself...

Comment: @DebajyotiDas You can bind to the `image.load` event for the `<img />` element.

Comment: Can you have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21228290/making-certain-methods-work-for-window-onload-function-before-load?lq=1