# Making Certain methods work for $(window).on("load", function () { before load

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/FyrRm/1/

You will notice as we scroll down... After scrolling to the article headline to `<div class="share"></div>` I am showing a share widget. I am using `$(window).on("load", function () {` to make sure that the background image gets loaded first so that the script works the [way I want it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20789245/jquery-scroll-with-positionfixed-css) to.

But the problem is if the user scrolls beyond `.share` before the image loads fully, then the `share-active` div is not loaded. How can I fix this ?

Also, is there any way to add any effect while the share widget gets displayed like a jiggle etc so the users attention is drawn to it using jquery itself. I don't want to use jQ UI since its a huge file along side with JQ

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `jquery` code for showing the **share widgit div** at top *(also)* before the you call `$(window).on("load", function () {`
And include that particular `JS` file at top before the image `div`

And for some animation make a visit to [jQueryUi Effects](http://jqueryui.com/effect/)